# Why one needs two brackets to use macros in C?

Tags: c, macros, parentheses

```
    KdPrint(("Enter HelloWDMAddDevice\n"));
```

What's the reason for doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is so you can pass an entire argument list to the macro and have it pass it on to a function that takes a variable number of arguments.

I would bet anything that the definition of that macro is:

```
#if DEBUG /* or something like it */
#define KdPrint(args) (printf args)
#else
#define KdPrint(args) /* empty */
#endif
```

Or similar to some other function that works just like printf.

If it were defined as printf(args), then you could only pass the single string argument, because an argument to a macro can't contain a comma that isn't inside a nested parenthesis.

Comment: You are probably right! But I think the one who wrote this macro doesn't do a good job. He should have put brackets around 'args'.

Comment: No, the point is args might be more than one thing with a comma, so it _has_ to be parenthesized outside the macro.

Comment: GCC supports [variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), so if you can be sure the code will always be compiled with GCC, you can `#define KdPrint(...) (printf __VA_ARGS__)`.

Comment: Variadic macro support is not just a GCC thing, it's [standard C99 and C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro).

Answer (score 4):

It causes everything inside the parens to be treated as a single parameter to the macro.  In the example shown, it can allow for varargs types of parameters:

```
KdPrint(( "My info is %s\n", "my name" ));
```

As well as

```
KdPrint(( "fn %s ln %s\n", "my", "name" ));
```

Answer (score 3):

If the macro in question was not well written using parentheses, it might be necessary because of operator precedence. Take this macro for example:

```
#define MY_MACRO(a) a * 11
```

Well, if you did this:

```
int b = MY_MACRO(1 + 2);
```

`b`, instead of being 33 like it should, would actually be replaced with `int b = 1 + 2 * 11` which is 23 and not 33. If your macro isn't written like that, though (without parenthesis around the `a`) then it's unnecessary.

Comment: Although insightful about macro gotchas, if this was really the problem then KdPrint would place brackets within the macro itself. It's *far* more likely that a) it needs to pass all parameters to a function that takes a variable number of arguments, or b) it tries to be compatible with preprocessors that don't support __VA_ARGS__, meaning you have to pass all arguments as a single macro argument until they reach the function level.

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the `KdPrint()` that you are talking about, then this is because you can use `KdPrint()` macro with format arguments, and it is not a variable length macro.

For example, you can do:

```
KdPrint(("The answer is %d\n", 42));
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, I cannot tell you, because I don't know what is XdPrint.

But in a more general case, it is because a macro I just like a search and replace. Suppose you have:

```
#define MULT(a,b) (a*b)
```

If you call `MULT(1+1, 2+2)`, it would become `1+1*2+2`, and result as `5` instead of `8` as you would expect. Doing `MULT((1+1), (2+2))` would gives you the expected result. That is why you need to double the brackets.