# Behaviour of macro changes when used with parenthesis

Tags: c, macros

Why is `max(0,1)` behaving differently than `max(1,0)` in this program?

```
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)
int main()
{
    printf("max(0,1)    = %d \n",max(0,1));
    printf("max(0,1)+1  = %d \n",max(0,1)+1);
    printf("max(0,1)+2  = %d \n",max(0,1)+2);
    printf("max(1,0)    = %d \n",max(1,0));
    printf("max(1,0)+1  = %d \n",(max(1,0)+1));
    printf("max(1,0)+2  = %d \n",(max(1,0)+2));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
max(0,1) = 1
max(0,1)+1 = 2
max(0,1)+2 = 3
max(0,1) = 1
max(1,0)+1= 1
max(1,0)+2= 1
```

And why do these behave well if one extra parenthesis is used?

```
#define max(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
```

Comment: Think about the result of the expansion: `max(0,1)+1` => `((0)>(1))?(0):(1)+1` which is equivalent to `(0 > 1)? 0 : (1 + 1)` in the first case, and different from `(((0)>(1))?(0):(1))+1` which is basically `((0 > 1)? 0 : 1) + 1`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812877/why-one-needs-two-brackets-to-use-macros-in-c-c

Answer (score 2):

Because the `?:` conditional operator has lower operator precedence than the binary `+` operator.

Thus `max(1,0)+1` gets interpreted as `1>0?1:(0+1)`

Perfect example of why you shouldn't use function-like macros.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator `? :` has a very low operator precedence: much lower than addition. Therefore you need to put the ternary in brackets so, when it's used to compute a maximum, the final addition, if any, is computed *after* the ternary.

You can always resort to *unpicking* a macro:

`max(1,0) + 1` unpicks, with your first definition of `max` to `(1) > (0) ? (1) : (0) + 1` which is, of course, `1`. With the second definition it is `((1) > (0) ? (1) : (0)) + 1` which is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

After the macro expansion `#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)`, your statements

```
printf("max(0,1)+1  = %d \n",max(0,1)+1);
printf("max(1,0)+1  = %d \n",(max(1,0)+1));
```

looks like

```
printf("max(0,1)+1  = %d \n",0 > 1 ? 0: (1+1));
printf("max(1,0)+1  = %d \n",(1 > 0 ? 1: (0+1)));
```